# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.idbc.Driver problem

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection, mysql-connector

So I have a problem concerning the MySql Connector Driver. Even tho I have added the library it still shows the same error as shown in the image.

[image: ClassNotFoundException Image]

Everything goes fine till it gets to the method where I need to write the data to MySQL. I also tried importing the library but it goes gray then disappears just after I press;

I tried importing the Library from Maven and also manually the same problem still happens. I use IntelliJ IDEA.

Here is also the code that I have in the Java Class:

```
package sample.database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseHandler extends Configs {
    private Connection dbConnection;

    public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String connectionString = "idbc:mysql://"+ dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" +dbName;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.idbc.Driver");

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,dbUser,dbPass);

        return dbConnection;
    }

    //write method
    public void SignUpUser(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName) {

        String insert = "INSERT INTO"+Const.USERS_TABLE+"("+Const.USERNAME+","+Const.PASSWORD+","+Const.NAME+","+Const.LASTNAME+")"+"VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            getDbConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insert);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, userName);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, firstName);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, lastName);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, yours seems more like a typographic mistake. There is nothing like idbc as far as I knew. Change idbc to jdbc and try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've accidentally misspelled "jdbc" in this code,  replace "idbc" with "jdbc".

jdbc stands for Java Database Connectivity :)

Comment: @MartinKataroski You made the same mistake three times: in your title, your `Class.forName()` line, which you can remove, and your database URL.

Comment: I fixed that now I have one more problem. I also changed the PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insert); to PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
problem showing up:
Could not create connection to database server.
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: Based on the link below, this might be caused by MySQL not being up/accessible locally. Is MySQL running when this error occurs? 

https://www.edureka.co/community/37660/mysql-could-not-create-connection-to-database-serve-error